# reactjs input return undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Input returning undefined, I also added onChange function to the input, this.state.quantity returns undefined in the console

**OrderMed.js:**

```
export default class OrderMed extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Meds: [],
      quantity: '',
      id:''
    }
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }
  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({quantity: e.target.quantity})
  }
render() {
    return ( 
...
<form >
 <input min={1} placeholder='quantity' type='number' value={this.state.quantity} onChange={this.onChange} id="quantity"></input>
 <button onClick={() => console.log(this.state.quantity)} id='btn-color1' class="btn btn-color ml-2 px-3 mb-2 w-1">&#10003;</button> 
</form>
...
 )
}
```

Comment: `{quantity: e.target.quantity}` should be `{quantity: e.target.value}` in your `onChange` function

Comment: my dumb brain! was fighting with this for hours

Comment: You have a couple other issues. `class=` should be `className`, and the button needs `type="button"` otherwise it will submit the form

Answer (score 1):

you just should set event.target.value in onChange function
like this:

```
onChange(e) {
    this.setState({quantity: e.target.value})
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should go for arrow functions rather than the old fashion ones it reduces complexities and you missed the value of the target element

```js
export default class OrderMed extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Meds: [],
      quantity: '',
      id:''
    }
  }
  onChange = (e) => {
    const quantity  = e.target.value;

    this.setState({quantity})
  }
render() {
    return ( 
...
<form >
 <input min={1} placeholder='quantity' type='number' value={this.state.quantity} onChange={this.onChange} id="quantity"></input>
 <button onClick={() => console.log(this.state.quantity)} id='btn-color1' class="btn btn-color ml-2 px-3 mb-2 w-1">&#10003;</button> 
</form>
...
 )
}
```